# Why the value of conversationsCounter is 436 and not 0,1,2,3,4,5....when clicking on add?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger _conversationTrigger;

    [SerializeField] private ReorderableList conversationsList;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private int _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;
    private int newSize = 0;
    private Vector2 scrollPos;
    int conversationsCounter = 0;

    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _dialoguesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, ReorderableList> _sentencesListDict = new Dictionary<string, ReorderableList>();

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversationTrigger = (ConversationTrigger)target;
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");

        conversationsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _conversations)
        {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,

            drawHeaderCallback = DrawConversationsHeader,

            drawElementCallback = DrawConversationsElement,

            onAddCallback = (list) =>
            {
                conversationsCounter += 1;

                SerializedProperty addedElement;
                // if something is selected add after that element otherwise on the end
                if (_currentlySelectedConversationIndex >= 0)
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.InsertArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(_currentlySelectedConversationIndex + 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                    addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);
                }

                var name = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                var foldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                var dialogues = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

                name.stringValue = "";
                foldout.boolValue = false;
                dialogues.arraySize = 0;
            },

            elementHeightCallback = (index) =>
            {
                return GetConversationHeight(_conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index));
            }
        };
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if there are no elements reset _currentlySelectedConversationIndex
        if (conversationsList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1 < _currentlySelectedConversationIndex) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = -1;

        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Conversations", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();
        {
            newSize = EditorGUILayout.IntField(_conversations.arraySize);
        }
        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            if (newSize > _conversations.arraySize)
            {
                // elements have to be added -> how many?
                var toAdd = newSize - _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                // why -1 ? -> We add the first element and set its values to default
                // now if we simply increase the arraySize for the rest of the elements
                // they will be all a copy of the first -> all defaults ;)

                // first add one element
                _conversations.arraySize++;
                // then get that element
                var newIndex = _conversations.arraySize - 1;
                var newElement = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(newIndex);

                // now reset all properties like
                var name = newElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                name.stringValue = "";

                // now for the rest simply increase arraySize
                _conversations.arraySize += toAdd;
            }
            else
            {
                // for removing just make sure the arraySize is not under 0
                _conversations.arraySize = Mathf.Max(newSize, 0);
            }
        }

        scrollPos = EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Height(250));

        GUILayout.Space(10);
        conversationsList.DoLayoutList();

        EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            _conversationTrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(_conversationTrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            _conversationTrigger.LoadConversations();
        }

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    #region Drawers

    #region List Headers

    private void DrawConversationsHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        //EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Conversations");
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Dialogues");
    }

    private void DrawSentencesHeader(Rect rect)
    {
        EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, "Sentences");
    }

    #endregion List Headers

    #region Elements

    private void DrawConversationsElement(Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (isActive) _currentlySelectedConversationIndex = index;

        var conversation = _conversations.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var name = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");
        string dialoguesListKey = conversation.propertyPath;

        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            //GUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 15, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), itemscounter.ToString());
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation " + conversationsCounter.ToString()/*foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue*/,true);

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_dialoguesListDict.ContainsKey(dialoguesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var dialoguesList = new ReorderableList(conversation.serializedObject, dialogues)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawDialoguesHeader,

                        drawElementCallback = (convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused) => { DrawDialoguesElement(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey], convRect, convIndex, convActive, convFocused); },

                        elementHeightCallback = (dialogIndex) =>
                        {
                            return GetDialogueHeight(_dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(dialogIndex));
                        },

                        onAddCallback = (list) =>
                        {
                            list.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(list.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            var newDialoguesName = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Name");
                            var newDialoguesFoldout = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
                            var sentences = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

                            newDialoguesName.stringValue = "";
                            newDialoguesFoldout.boolValue = true;
                            sentences.arraySize = 0;
                        }
                    };
                    _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey] = dialoguesList;
                }

                _dialoguesListDict[dialoguesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }

        }
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
    }

    private void DrawDialoguesElement(ReorderableList list, Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused)
    {
        if (list == null) return;

        var dialog = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        var position = new Rect(rect);

        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");
        var name = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Name");

        {
            // make the label be a foldout
            foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue);

            var sentencesListKey = dialog.propertyPath;
            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            if (foldout.boolValue)
            {
                // draw the name field
                name.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextField(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), name.stringValue);
                position.y += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

                if (!_sentencesListDict.ContainsKey(sentencesListKey))
                {
                    // create reorderabl list and store it in dict
                    var sentencesList = new ReorderableList(sentences.serializedObject, sentences)
                    {
                        displayAdd = true,
                        displayRemove = true,
                        draggable = true,

                        // header for the dialog list
                        drawHeaderCallback = DrawSentencesHeader,

                        // how a sentence is displayed
                        drawElementCallback = (sentenceRect, sentenceIndex, sentenceIsActive, sentenceIsFocused) =>
                        {
                            var sentence = sentences.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentenceIndex);

                            // draw simple textArea for sentence
                            sentence.stringValue = EditorGUI.TextArea(sentenceRect, sentence.stringValue);
                        },

                        // Sentences have simply a fixed height of 2 lines
                        elementHeight = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 2,

                        // when a sentence is added
                        onAddCallback = (sentList) =>
                        {
                            sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize++;
                            var addedElement = sentList.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(sentList.serializedProperty.arraySize - 1);

                            addedElement.stringValue = "";
                        }
                    };

                    // store the created ReorderableList
                    _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey] = sentencesList;
                }

                // Draw the list
                _sentencesListDict[sentencesListKey].DoList(new Rect(position.x, position.y, position.width, position.height - EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight));
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Elements

    #endregion Drawers


    #region Helpers

    #region HeightGetter

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Conversation property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="conversation"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Conversation property</returns>
    private float GetConversationHeight(SerializedProperty conversation)
    {
        var foldout = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // if not foldout the height is simply 1 line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise we sum up every controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 5;


            var dialogues = conversation.FindPropertyRelative("Dialogues");

            for (var d = 0; d < dialogues.arraySize; d++)
            {
                var dialog = dialogues.GetArrayElementAtIndex(d);
                height += GetDialogueHeight(dialog);
            }
        }

        return height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the height of given Dialogue property
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dialog"></param>
    /// <returns>height of given Dialogue property</returns>
    private float GetDialogueHeight(SerializedProperty dialog)
    {
        var foldout = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Foldout");

        // same game for the dialog if not foldout it is only a single line
        var height = EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;

        // otherwise sum up controls and child heights
        if (foldout.boolValue)
        {
            // we need some more lines:
            //  for the Name field,
            // the list header,
            // the list buttons and a bit buffer
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * 4;

            var sentences = dialog.FindPropertyRelative("Sentences");

            // the sentences are easier since they always have the same height
            // in this example 2 lines so simply do
            // at least have space for 1 sentences even if there is none
            height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight * Mathf.Max(1, sentences.arraySize) * 2;
        }

        return height;
    }

    #endregion

    #endregion Helpers
}
```

At the top I added the variable conversationsCounter and init it to 0
Inside the OnEnable inside onAddCallback I'm raising the conversationsCounter each time by 1

```
conversationsCounter += 1;
```

Inside DrawConversationsElement I'm drawing the items with the name "Conversation " and the counter :

```
foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation " + conversationsCounter.ToString(),true);
```

This line was before :

```
foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, foldout.boolValue ? "" : name.stringValue,true);
```

This part :

```
"Conversation " + conversationsCounter.ToString()
```

But it's not adding the value 1,2,3,4,5 next each Conversation
It's showing other values and when moving the mouse over it in the editor it keep changing the values.

Comment: It's because the increment of the counter happens separately from putting its value into a string. I don't know much about `ReorderableList` but maybe you can add an conversation index `SerializedProperty` to a conversation and then in `onAddCallback` use FindPropertyRelative to get that conversation index and set it to the current value of conversationsCounter. Then in `DrawConversationsElement` you can get the conversation index that you set earlier and make the string out of that instead of `conversationCounter`.

Comment: what about simply going by `(index + 1).ToString()` ?

Comment: @derHugo If I'm doing : foldout.boolValue = EditorGUI.Foldout(new Rect(position.x, position.y, 10, EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight), foldout.boolValue, "Conversation Name " + (index + 1).ToString(), true); It's showing 0 for all the items. For example if I have 4 conversations all of them have index 0.

Answer (score 2):

## Because, like all IMGUI magic methods, `OnInspectorGUI` is called more than once.

Unity calls `OnGui` and `OnInspectorGUI` *as many times as needed* each "frame" in order to do the things it needs to do. If nothing at all happens (i.e. the base case) the function is called twice: once for layout and once for drawing (repaint).

On top of those two calls there are calls for mouse interaction, as well as other potential events that might interact with the GUI. These things are not very well documented and there's no IMGUI debugger hooks yet (its on the far-future roadmap), so getting an exact count of what calls IMGUI functions is not easy.

As such, you should not do things that depend on an exact number of calls.

Comment: The idea was to number the Conversation 1,2,3,4,5...each time adding a conversation give it a number. I understand it's calling many times.

Comment: Either using int variable or SerialllllllllllizedProperty like conversationsCounter = addedElement.FindPropertyRelative("ConversationIndex"); and increase the value by one inside the onAddCallback will increase the int value by 1 fine each click. But still it won't work fine in the OnEnable. I can't figure out how to do it.